# How to pass variables to a function and return some of their properties javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, drop-down-menu, attributes

I have a drop down menu and when I select an element I want to see a list of information about this element.
The drop down and selection work but since I have lot of options (more than showing) I try to make a function that will return the information for the element selected so I don't repeat my code. But my function give me an error message:"Cannot read property 'top_1' of undefined" but console.log(obj.top_1) works fine.

```
var obj = {
  top_1 :"bla",
  top_2 :"bla bla",
  objDetail_1 :{ top_1 :"bli",
            top_2 :"bli bli",
            name1:"AAA",
            name2:"AAAA"
            },
  objDetail_2 :{ top_1 :"blo",
            top_2 :"bli blo",
            name1:"BBB",
            name2:"BBBBB"
            }           
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.myStuff li ul li').click( function(event){
    $(document).find('#description').css('visibility', 'visible');
    var idElement = $(this).attr('id');

    if (idElement == 'top_1'){
            console.log(obj.top_1);
            ing(obj, top_1);
    };

    function ing(element1, element2){
        console.log(element1.top_1 +" "+ element1.top_2 +" "+element1.element2.top_1+" "+ element1.element2.top_2);
    };
  });
});
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Not sure what you want to do, but you should note that ing(obj, top_1); --> top_1 is undefined

Comment: You are right thank you! it needs to be ing(obj, obj.top_1) and function ing(element1, element2){
        console.log(element1.top_1 +" "+ element1.top_2 +" "+element2.top_1+" "+element2.top_2);
    };

Comment: Whenever I see variables or property names ending in numbers, it's a red flag to me that it should probably be an array.

Comment: @Letincel It's still unclear what you're trying to do there. If `element2` is `obj.top_1`, how can you access `element2.top_1`. That would be `obj.top_1.top_1`, but `opj.top_1` is a string, not an object. Did you mean `obj.objDetail_1.top_1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass `element2` as a string and replace it by `objDetail_1` like this:

```
ing(obj, "objDetail_1");
```

Then in the function body access the properties like this:

```
function ing(element1, element2){
  console.log(element1.top_1, element1.top_2,
    element1[element2].top_1, element1[element2].top_2);
};
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ing(obj, "objDetail_1")`?

Comment: @Barmar Indeed. The OP has written `top_1` in the original code. I’ll correct it.

Comment: Although now it’s even more confusing… isn’t `element1` and `element2` intended to be for `objDetail_1` and `objDetail_2`? Besides: You could as well only pass `obj` to `console.log`. As far as I know modern browsers, should support some sort of object analysis whith which you can view the object properties.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but try that way:

```
function ing(element1, element2){
  console.log( element1[top_1] +" "+ 
   element1[top_2] +" "+element1[element2][top_1]+
   " "+ element1[element2][top_2] );
};
```

Comment: That will try to use the values of the variables `top_1` and `top_2` as the property names. But there are no such variables.

Comment: I think, that he try use variable like key in object, and it cannot be in .call

Answer (score 0):

I have a very hard time understanding what exactly is happening and what **should** be happening in your code - if you could create a JS fiddle or elaborate a bit on your problem, that would be great.

Anyway, there is an obvious problem in the `ing` function - your are trying to read a property `element2` on element1 and there is no such property! You should write element1[element2].top1. But the rest depends on what exactly are the contents of the variable `top_1`...

Comment: If you're not sure what he's trying to do, you should post a comment to try to get clarification.  Your answer doesn't really explain how to fix the code.

Comment: Duly noted, thanks! What's the correct approach now, do I delete the answer and put its contents into a comment?